# Reset value from Java Object

Tags: java, json, oop, gson

I am new in java and have such problem:

I  have a class POJO:

```
     @Parcel
    public class MyObjectClass {

        @SerializedName("data_1")
        private int dataOne;

        @SerializedName("data_2")
        private String dataTwo;

       // getter and setter

     }
```

I got a json source and using GSON librray I am initialize this object like:

```
 Gson gson = new Gson();
 MyObjectClass obj = gson.fromJson(myJsonString, MyObjectClass.class);
```

now I can acces values `data_1` and `data_2` from obj using getters

can I **change only one value from object** like `data_2` to be old one seted up by json and `data_1` to have new value ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need to store the old value in a variable if you want to keep it. For example :

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
MyObjectClass obj = gson.fromJson(myJsonString, MyObjectClass.class);
obj.setDataTwo("new value"); // with your setter method name for dataTwo
```

or for dataOne :

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
MyObjectClass obj = gson.fromJson(myJsonString, MyObjectClass.class);
obj.setDataOne(2); // with your setter method name for dataOne
```

**EDIT : updated code to better fit needs**

Comment: well, the question is that I am setting up object with values from json string, and **after** that I need to update it with new value...

Comment: where does the new value come from? in this case just use the setter with the new value

Comment: I will put it, for exemple I have in json that dataOne=1 but after that I'll set it to be another int value:2,3,4...